# UWP on desktop closed by top X button - no event

Tags: c#, desktop-application, uwp

An UWP app which runs on desktop can be closed from the top X button but it doesn't have any event for it. It is known that on phones and tablets an app should rely on `Suspending` event, no matter how it's triggered and then the app should rely on [`ApplicationExecutionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx).

However, here is a (maybe) common scenario: on phones the `Suspending` event suffice and in case a Voip call is going on it will be operated by OS after the app is suspended. **On desktop the close button is expected, by user, to completely close the app.** So if a call is on going it should be hanged up and certain resources should be released.

How can I know when the user clicked the "close" button if (and only if) the UWP app is running on desktop?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A [restricted capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) `confirmAppClose` was added in Windows 10 version 1703 (build 10.0.15063) in order to provide apps the ability to intercept window closing.

Manifest namespace:

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

Manifest:

```
<Capabilities> 
  <Capability Name="internetClient" /> 
  <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/> 
</Capabilities>
```

It needs extra approval when submitting to the store.  But then will fire the `CloseRequested` event on a [SystemNavigationManagerPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview) instance.

Code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += this.OnCloseRequest;
    }

    private void OnCloseRequest(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!saved) { e.Handled = true; SomePromptFunction(); }
    }
```

You can get a deferral to do a bit of work here (save or prompt), or you can set `Handled` to true in order to stop the window from closing (user cancelled prompt).

Comment: I saw the documentation pages you shared the link to, but i still dont know how to do it. Can you guide me how to register a handler for that event, in my window?

Comment: There's a blog someone posted about it here: http://codeworks.it/blog/?tag=systemnavigationmanagerpreview

Comment: Interesting - Intellisense shows the rescap:Capabilty node in appxmanifest with a squiggly underline indicating the capability doesn't exist, however the code compiles and the capability becomes active with this addition.

Comment: @zax I'm not sure why VS can't figure out the pieces, but that's also why they have the `IgnorableNamespaces` tag on the Package.  You can add rescap there to remove the squiggles.

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT The squiggles and associated pop-up error text are present *with* rescap added to IgnorableNamespaces.  VS 2017, 15.8.4.

Comment: Hmm, I'd log an issue with the VS feedback tools then.

Answer (score 4):

From official [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243287.aspx) about app lifecycle:

> There's no special event to indicate that the user closed the app.
>
> Closed-by-user behavior:  If your app needs to do something different when it is closed by the user than when it is closed by Windows, you can use the activation event handler to determine whether the app was terminated by the user or by Windows.

So according to this there is **no (clear) way to know if the user closed the app** before the app is closed but only after it's restarted. Too bad.

Comment: I guess it sorta make sense not to fire a close event. What if someone re-open another window at Closed? Is it achievable? Probably.

Comment: @Hiro I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "re-open another window at Closed". Anyway, needs vary from case to case and therefore it might makes sense to have a Closed event or to ignore it. For the record WinForms and WPF have it.

Comment: This is outdated now, I posted an updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This code helps you -

In **App.xaml.cs**

```
...
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
...

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
...
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //Add your logic here, if any
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my original answer with [Window.Current.Closed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.closed) event, because it doesn't seem to work if you have only one Window instance. There is also `CoreApplication.Exiting`, but judging by [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83678420-f395-4952-a0e9-864e83b457ad/coreapplicationexiting-never-got-called-in-c-xaml-app) topic it doesn't work either. Seems to be known issue which might be fixed in future. At the end, it appears there is no clear way to determine when the app is getting closed, only when it's suspended.

However, `Window.Current` does fire [VisibilityChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged) event when app is closed. Problem is, it's also fired when app is minimized and maybe in some other cases. But I think in combination with `Suspending` you can (more or less) safely determine that desktop app is closing. Good thing is, `VisibilityChanged` fired before `Suspending` and you can save it's value and check it in `OnSuspending` handler, after which decide if you need to do any cleaning up or other work.

Comment: But `VisibilityChanged` event will be fired when the OS closes the app as well. So there is no difference between OS-closing and user-closing.

Comment: Yes, OS can close the app as well, but it does so when it needs to free resources, which could be a quite rare case in desktop. Anyway, as I pointed before - it appears there is no clear way to determine when the app is getting closed by user.

Comment: So we can *guess* the app has been closed if we get the `VisibilityChanged` followed by the `Suspending` event.  Can this not occur naturally if the user minimizes the app and later Windows decides to suspend our app?  Then we would have incorrectly *guessed* the app is closing, as the user can later maximize it and resume?

Comment: Yes, in this case our guess will probably be incorrect. As I mentioned before, there seems to be no clear way to determine if app is closed by user unless you're checking it on the next launch.

Answer (score 1):

For those who find this question looking for how to confirm closing of a `Window` in WinUI3:

The `Window.Closed` event args has a `Handled` property which can be set to `true` to cancel the close.

I was really confused that `Closed`, in contrast to WPF can still be cancelled.