# UWP JS Prevent Suspension of Application

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp

Currently i am trying to prevent closing the application in windows uwp using javascript.

Below are code which i have tried

```html
 function suspending(e) {
            console.log("****** suspending start ******");
            var deferral = e.suspendingOperation.getDeferral();
            deferral.complete();
            console.log("****** suspending end ******");

        }
        //raised when the app gets suspended
        function resuming(args) {
            console.log("****** resuming ******");
        }
        Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("suspending", suspending, false);
        Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resuming, false);
```

I am able to log suspension event but resuming event is not working.

Even i have to run background tasks when suspension is carried out.

Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Your code worked well on my side. The `resuming` event could be fired successfully. See [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq). How did you take the operation to determine if the `resuming` event is not triggered?

Comment: i tried the console log of visual studio to check the resuming event.

Comment: when do you think the `resuming` event will be fired?

Comment: i think when we maximize??

Comment: Reading and understanding the whole [UWP app lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) to check your operations that you think the `resuming` event will be fired.

Comment: Can we get the control of close button using uwp js??

Comment: Please check this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056464/uwp-on-desktop-closed-by-top-x-button-no-event