# Can we cancel Secondary view's Consolidated event of UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

We're developing a UWP app and we want secondary view not to be closed.
Can we cancel Secondary view's Consolidated event?

Comment: You cannot cancel Consolidated (or any other past-tense event) because past-tense events are notifications that something has already happened. You need an event that occurs *before* the thing you want to prevent, such as [SystemNavigationManagerPreview.CloseRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview.closerequested).

Comment: Thank you. I found this article when searching that event. This is the answer I wanted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056464/uwp-on-desktop-closed-by-top-x-button-no-event?rq=1