# How to get instance of main AppWindow?

Tags: uwp

I need to get instance of AppWindow that opens by default. How to do it? I need it to track the window closing event.

Maybe i can do this using Windows.UI?

Answer (score 0):

There is a static `Window.Current` property that you can use to get a reference to the window of the current thread.

There is no `Closing` event available in UWP though so if you want to handle an event when your app is being shutdown, you need the `confirmAppClose` capability:

[UWP on desktop closed by top X button - no event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056464/uwp-on-desktop-closed-by-top-x-button-no-event)

Answer (score 0):

> How to get instance of main AppWindow?

If you mentioned `AppWindow` is using to show multiple views, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window#track-instances-of-appwindow).

In this document, it tells track instances of AppWindow [three ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window#track-instances-of-appwindow) Simple tracking, Track an AppWindow instance in its hosted content and Tracking app windows using UIContext.

And AppWindow contains [Closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.windowmanagement.appwindow.closed) event, you need to release resources when a window is closed.

```
appWindow.Closed += delegate
{
    appWindowContentFrame.Content = null;
    appWindow = null;
};
```